# Не выполняется запрос к БД (MSSQL) используя php

Tags: php, sql-server, база-данных

Проблема в следующем:
Написал запрос протестировал его через клиента MSSQL все отлично результат выдает.
Вставляю его в php, пишет ничего не найдено.
Сам запрос в MSSQL:

```
    SELECT a1.INCIDENT_ID, dateadd(hour,8,c1.OPEN_TIME), a1.BRIEF_DESCRIPTION, a1.ACTION, a1.NUMBER, a1.CATEGORY, dateadd(hour,8,c1.UPDATE_TIME), a1.ASSIGNMENT, a1.STATUS, a1.CLOSE_TIME, a1.CLOSED_BY,
       a1.VENDOR, a1.REFERENCE_NO, a1.CAUSE_CODE, a1.RESOLUTION_CODE, a1.RESOLUTION, a1.ASSIGNEE_NAME, 
       a1.UPDATE_ACTION, a1.ACTOR, a1.OPEN_GROUP, a1.CLOSING_COMMENTS, a1.UPDATED_BY, a1.PROBLEM_STATUS,
       a1.SUBCATEGORY, a1.SYSMODUSER, b1.OPER_BIZDESC, b1.CALLBACK_CONTACT_DEPT, b1.CALLBACK_CONTACT,
       c1.ALTERNATE_CONTACT 
FROM PROBSUMMARYM1 a1, PROBSUMMARYM2 b1, INCIDENTSM1 c1
WHERE a1.NUMBER=b1.NUMBER AND a1.INCIDENT_ID=c1.INCIDENT_ID AND b1.CALLBACK_CONTACT_DEPT='Отдел/Под отдел/Наше подразделение' ORDER BY a1.INCIDENT_ID DESC
```

В результате выводит все записи, согласно условию.
Вот тот же запрос только в php:

```
    $sql = "SELECT a1.INCIDENT_ID, dateadd(hour,8,c1.OPEN_TIME), a1.BRIEF_DESCRIPTION, a1.ACTION, a1.NUMBER, a1.CATEGORY, dateadd(hour,8,c1.UPDATE_TIME), a1.ASSIGNMENT, a1.STATUS, a1.CLOSE_TIME, a1.CLOSED_BY,
       a1.VENDOR, a1.REFERENCE_NO, a1.CAUSE_CODE, a1.RESOLUTION_CODE, a1.RESOLUTION, a1.ASSIGNEE_NAME, 
       a1.UPDATE_ACTION, a1.ACTOR, a1.OPEN_GROUP, a1.CLOSING_COMMENTS, a1.UPDATED_BY, a1.PROBLEM_STATUS,
       a1.SUBCATEGORY, a1.SYSMODUSER, b1.OPER_BIZDESC, b1.CALLBACK_CONTACT_DEPT, b1.CALLBACK_CONTACT,
       c1.ALTERNATE_CONTACT 
FROM PROBSUMMARYM1 a1, PROBSUMMARYM2 b1, INCIDENTSM1 c1
WHERE a1.NUMBER=b1.NUMBER AND a1.INCIDENT_ID=c1.INCIDENT_ID AND b1.CALLBACK_CONTACT_DEPT='%" . $ntofks . "%' ORDER BY a1.INCIDENT_ID DESC";
```

Результат: ничего не найдено.
Передаваемые переменные выводил отдельно с ними все нормально.Пробовал без переменной $ntofks, заменял ее на 'Отдел/Под отдел/Наше подразделение', результата тоже нет - ноль записей.
Подскажите что не так делаю?уже мозг сломал.
Чуть не забыл, запрос работает если если запрашиваю данные на латинеце по полу идентифатора:

```
    $sql = "SELECT a1.INCIDENT_ID, dateadd(hour,8,c1.OPEN_TIME), a1.BRIEF_DESCRIPTION, a1.ACTION, a1.NUMBER, a1.CATEGORY, dateadd(hour,8,c1.UPDATE_TIME), a1.ASSIGNMENT, a1.STATUS, a1.CLOSE_TIME, a1.CLOSED_BY,
       a1.VENDOR, a1.REFERENCE_NO, a1.CAUSE_CODE, a1.RESOLUTION_CODE, a1.RESOLUTION, a1.ASSIGNEE_NAME, 
       a1.UPDATE_ACTION, a1.ACTOR, a1.OPEN_GROUP, a1.CLOSING_COMMENTS, a1.UPDATED_BY, a1.PROBLEM_STATUS,
       a1.SUBCATEGORY, a1.SYSMODUSER, b1.OPER_BIZDESC, b1.CALLBACK_CONTACT_DEPT, b1.CALLBACK_CONTACT,
       c1.ALTERNATE_CONTACT 
FROM PROBSUMMARYM1 a1, PROBSUMMARYM2 b1, INCIDENTSM1 c1
WHERE a1.NUMBER=b1.NUMBER AND a1.INCIDENT_ID=c1.INCIDENT_ID AND a1.NUMBER LIKE '%" . $word . "%' ORDER BY a1.INCIDENT_ID DESC";
```

Скрипт index.php(страница с формой):

```
    <?php
header ('Content-Tpe: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Поиск обращений и инцидентов</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">
<!--Подключение стилей-->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/dop.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- le html5 SHIM, FOR ie6-8 SUPPORT OF HTML5 ELEMENT -->
        <!-- [IF lT IE 9]>
        <script src="assests/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif] -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h3 style="text-align:center;">Введите номер Инцидента и нажмите кнопку "ПОИСК"</h3>
<div id="container">
<div style="margin:20px auto; text-align: center;">
<form class="form-search" method="post" action="do_search.php">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search_box" class='input-medium search_box' placeholder="Введите номер инцидента"/>
    <select name="ntofk" placeholder="Выберете ваш отдел" class="input-xxlarge">
    <option>Отдел1/ под1 отдел/ наш1 отдел</option>
    <option>Отдел2/ под2 отдел/ наш2 отдел</option>
    <option></option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary search_button">Поиск</button><br />
</form>
</div>
<div>
<div id="searchresults">Результаты для <span class="word"></span></div>
<table id="results" class="table">
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Скрипт поиска search.php:

```
    <?php
//получаем данные через $_POST

    // подключаемся к базе
    include('db.php');
    $db = new db();

    $word =$_POST['search'];
    $nt = $_POST['ntofk'];
    $ntofks =str_replace('//','////', $nt);
    // Строим запрос

$sql = "SELECT a1.INCIDENT_ID, dateadd(hour,8,c1.OPEN_TIME), a1.BRIEF_DESCRIPTION, a1.ACTION, a1.NUMBER, a1.CATEGORY, dateadd(hour,8,c1.UPDATE_TIME), a1.ASSIGNMENT, a1.STATUS, a1.CLOSE_TIME, a1.CLOSED_BY,
       a1.VENDOR, a1.REFERENCE_NO, a1.CAUSE_CODE, a1.RESOLUTION_CODE, a1.RESOLUTION, a1.ASSIGNEE_NAME, 
       a1.UPDATE_ACTION, a1.ACTOR, a1.OPEN_GROUP, a1.CLOSING_COMMENTS, a1.UPDATED_BY, a1.PROBLEM_STATUS,
       a1.SUBCATEGORY, a1.SYSMODUSER, b1.OPER_BIZDESC, b1.CALLBACK_CONTACT_DEPT, b1.CALLBACK_CONTACT,
       c1.ALTERNATE_CONTACT 
FROM PROBSUMMARYM1 a1, PROBSUMMARYM2 b1, INCIDENTSM1 c1
WHERE a1.NUMBER=b1.NUMBER AND a1.INCIDENT_ID=c1.INCIDENT_ID AND b1.CALLBACK_CONTACT_DEPT='%" . $ntofks . "%' ORDER BY a1.INCIDENT_ID DESC";

    // Получаем результаты
    $row = $db->select_list($sql);
    if(count($row)) {
        $end_result = '';
        foreach($row as $r) {
            $result         = $r['NUMBER'] . "".iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['ACTION'])."" ."".iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8", $r['CALLBACK_CONTACT_DEPT'])."";
            $bold           = '<div>' . $word . '</div>';
            $end_result     .= '<div>' . str_ireplace($word, $bold, $result) . '</div>';
        }
        echo $end_result;
    } else {
        echo '<tr>По вашему запросу ничего не найдено</tr>' . $ntofks . $word;
    }

?>
```

Ответ: По вашему запросу ничего не найдено и переменные которые передаю через POST

Comment: может из за слешей? если да то как их победить?

Comment: @mountpoint, насчет слеша, не корректно перенес информацию.

Comment: @maxleo, в этом направление тоже думал, я видать протупил не втом порядке декодировал, к сожалению проверить смогу только на след день)

Comment: базы абсолютно идентичны? $db->select_list() работает корректно? Пробовали выполнять этот же запрос в adminer, pma?

Comment: да все нормально. Нашел в чем проблема,как написал @maxleo, проблема была в UTF-8 и в моей криворукости. Решение следующее:
В файле - search.php, полученную переменную перекодировал - 
$nt = iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251",$_POST['ntofk']);
Проблема была в том что я не в том порядке перекодировал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в UTF-8 и в моей криворукости.
В файле - search.php, полученную переменную перекодировал -

```
$nt = iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251",$_POST['ntofk']);
```

Изначально, я не в том порядке перекодировал.

Comment: всем спасибо за  помощь)

Answer (score 1):

там где в php:

```
b1.CALLBACK_CONTACT_DEPT='%" . $ntofks . "%'
```

может стоит написать c LIKE?

```
b1.CALLBACK_CONTACT_DEPT LIKE '%" . $ntofks . "%'
```

Comment: Пробовал, тоже по нулям. А м MSSQL запрос проходит и с LIKE

Comment: я в переменную вставляю:"Отдел\Под отдел\Наше подразделение"
Может обрубаются слеши?
я уже и кодировку у самой переменной менял:) результата ноль:)

Comment: попробуй проэкранировать слеши

str_replace('\\','\\\\', $sql);

Comment: тоже пробовал. не получается, сейчас выложу весь код.
Обновил информацию

Comment: а разве надо экранировать слеш - "/"?

Comment: @intertex, так у вас же обратный слеш \

Comment: Сдается мне, что дело в utf-8.